# Is it possible to display stdout in dialog-box or better human readable format in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I am new to Ansible and my play looks like this:

```yml
- name: "Spark Submit Command"
  shell: "{{ sparkCommand }}"
  register: spark_output

- debug: msg="{{ spark_output.stdout }}"
```

I have around 60 lines in my spark_output.stdout and getting the output as below:

```
ok: [DHADLX110] => {
    "msg": "Line1\nLine2\nLine3...........Line.."
```

Is it possible to print these line by line or in a proper dialog box? Something similar to below format:

```
Line1
Line2
.
.
.
Line60
```

Comment: Have you tried a debug of `var: spark_output`? It should solve your requirement. Hint: use `spark_output.stdout_lines`.

Comment: thnks its working now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you register command output, Ansible will give you `stdout` and `stdout_lines`.

If you change your debug task to:

```yml
- debug:
    var: spark_output
```

You will see that it also returns `stdout_lines`. So instead of `spark_output.stdout` use:

```yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ spark_output.stdout_lines }}"
```